# docker-compose build download few pom dependencies each time

Tags: maven, heroku, docker-compose, dockerfile, dropwizard

I am using [Heroku Java Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/heroku/java/) and [docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose) to run dropwizard java based web service locally.

When I run `docker-compose build web` command to build code, It goes to download few dependencies each time. So build process turnaround time increased.

My project docker file is only single line : `FROM heroku/java`

Here are build log:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building generator-app-server 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom (4 KB at 0.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom (13 KB at 9.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar (25 KB at 14.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ generator-app-server ---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.pom (4 KB at 5.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/spice/spice-parent/16/spice-parent-16.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/spice/spice-parent/16/spice-parent-16.pom (9 KB at 4.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/forge/forge-parent/5/forge-parent-5.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/forge/forge-parent/5/forge-parent-5.pom (9 KB at 5.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar (221 KB at 20.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Deleting /app/user/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ generator-app-server ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ generator-app-server ---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.1.0.Final/mapstruct-processor-1.1.0.Final.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.1.0.Final/mapstruct-processor-1.1.0.Final.jar (1502 KB at 24.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.1.0.Final/mapstruct-processor-1.1.0.Final.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.1.0.Final/mapstruct-processor-1.1.0.Final.pom (12 KB at 4.9 KB/sec)
```

`docker-compose build` not using cached dependencies for above libs. How to forcefully use cached dependencies?

Googled a lot but no luck. Share if anyone had faced and fixed.

**Update:**

```
Dockerfile
FROM heroku/java

docker-compose.yml
web:
  build: .
  command: 'bash -c ''java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/generator-app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar db migrate config.yml && java $JAVA_OPTS -Ddw.server.connector.port=$PORT -jar target/generator-app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml'''
  working_dir: /app/user
  environment:
    PORT: 8080
    DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres:@herokuPostgresql:5432/postgres'
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
  links:
    - herokuPostgresql
shell:
  build: .
  command: bash
  working_dir: /app/user
  environment:
    PORT: 8080
    DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres:@herokuPostgresql:5432/postgres'
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
  links:
    - herokuPostgresql
  volumes:
    - '.:/app/user'
herokuPostgresql:
  image: postgres
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you wanna use a image you already built, you can use the **up** command instead of the **build**. However, if you have ADD or COPY in your Dockerfile and you modified the files, you will have to add the **--build** flag to rebuild the image.

Comment: @AndyShinn updated question

Comment: Can you provide the `docker-compose.yml` and enough of the services and files (`Dockerfile`, etc.) so that we can reproduce?

Comment: @FrançoisNoël I am using `heroku/java` inside my Dockerfile and building each time I change my code.

Comment: did u get a solution

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer didn't make sense (I mistakenly thought that Maven dependencies were handled at run time and they are handled at `ONBUILD` instructions instead). But I'll try to give a second explanation of why these specific dependencies are not cached.

The downloaded dependencies listed in the question are from the builtin plugins for Maven `clean`. In the parent `Dockerfile` we download the project dependencies at https://github.com/heroku/docker-java/blob/master/Dockerfile#L14 (everything in your POM). Then, later on in the `Dockerfile` it runs the `clean` at https://github.com/heroku/docker-java/blob/master/Dockerfile#L18. Since the `maven-clean-plugin` isn't part of your POM, it gets downloaded automatically at the clean step (it isn't cached from the previous `Dockerfile` instructions).

So, if you wanted to cache the `maven-clean-plugin` as well, you may need to add it as a dependency in your POM (you might be able to get away with just `<scope>import</scope>`).

Comment: Getting error: `[ERROR]     Malformed POM /app/user/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'scope' `, I think <plugin> has not <scope> tag.

Comment: I tried few ways but I didn't find any solution. Can you please suggest me if there is any other way.

Comment: I don't have any other ideas.